# Use variable in pd.read.sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have data in SQL and I want to read some data out from it with variable instead of using number like "953381". Having no idea why I just can't use `var = 9553381`, directly.

```
df = pd.read_sql('select name, data, from sheet where name = "953381" ', conn,
                index_col=['date'], parse_dates=['date'])
```

Comment: What is the error/output you are getting using this code?

Comment: DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql,  no such column: var

Comment: Is the extra comma after "data" causing the error?

Comment: Should be not, since I can get correct data if I using numbers, 953381.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't understand double quotes. Use single quotes:

```
x = "953381"
query = "SELECT name, data FROM sheet WHERE name = '%s'" % x # x inside single quotes
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, index_col=['date'], parse_dates=['date'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!!!  It works !!!!

Comment: Do not use string formatting to put SQL values into a query! This is never a good idea, it opens up the code for SQL injection attacks, and robs the database of an opportunity to reuse optimised queries. Use `?` or `%s` placeholders (depends on the database driver) and pass in the value to `read_sql()` via `params=(x,)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is what you are looking for:

```
var =  "953381" 
df = pd.read_sql('select name, data, from sheet where name =' + var, conn,
                index_col=['date'], parse_dates=['date'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you  are looking for ?

```
var = "953381"
df = pd.read_sql('select name, data, from sheet where name =' + var , conn,
            index_col=['date'], parse_dates=['date'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. but it  still can't find the data.

Comment: Do not use string formatting to put SQL values into a query! This is never a good idea, it opens up the code for SQL injection attacks, and robs the database of an opportunity to reuse optimised queries. Use `?` or `%s` placeholders (depends on the database driver) and pass in the value to `read_sql()` via `params=(x,)`.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a case for `.format()`?

```
x = "953381"
sql_str = 'select name, data, from sheet where name = "{}"'.format(x)
```

Comment: I tried, not this case, but thank you the suggestion!

Comment: Do not use string formatting to put SQL values into a query! This is never a good idea, it opens up the code for SQL injection attacks, and robs the database of an opportunity to reuse optimised queries. Use `?` or `%s` placeholders (depends on the database driver) and pass in the value to `read_sql()` via `params=(x,)`.